# Bott-Chern cohomology of the polydisc in $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Define the Bott-Chern cohomology of a complex manifold $X$ as
$$H^{p,q}_{BC}(X) := \frac{ \{ \alpha \in \mathcal{A}^{p,q}(X) | d\alpha = 0 \}}{\partial \overline{\partial}\mathcal{A}^{p-1,q-1}(X)}.$$

Does someone know how to prove the following statement: If $\Delta \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is a polydisc, then  $H^{p,q}_{BC}(\Delta)=0$?

Thanks !

Comment: What have you tried? Note that the statement boils down to proving that every $d$-closed $(p,q)$-form is $\partial\overline\partial$-exact, which is a Poincaré lemma-type statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to show that $d\alpha=0\iff \alpha=\partial\bar{\partial}\beta$ for some $\beta\in\Omega^{p-1,q-1}(\Delta)$. Suppose $d\alpha=0$. By the Poincaré lemma, $\alpha=d\gamma$ for some $\gamma\in\Omega^{p+q-1}(\Delta)$. Since $d=\partial+\bar{\partial}$, we may as well assume that $\gamma\in\Omega^{p,q-1}(\Delta)\oplus\Omega^{p-1,q}(\Delta)$, by projecting onto these summands if necessary. Denote the components by $\gamma=\gamma^{(p,q-1)}+\gamma^{(p-1,q)}$. Since $d\gamma=\alpha$ and $\alpha\in\Omega^{p,q}(\Delta)$, we must have $\partial\gamma^{(p,q-1)}=0$ and $\bar{\partial}\gamma^{(p-1,q)}=0$. Apply the $\partial$-Poincaré lemma and $\bar{\partial}$-Poincaré lemma to these summands to conclude that there exists $\beta'$ and $\beta''$ such that $\partial\beta'=\gamma^{(p,q-1)}$ and $\bar{\partial}\beta''=\gamma^{(p-1,q)}$. Now consider $\beta=-\beta'+\beta''$. Then $\bar{\partial}\beta=-\bar{\partial}\beta'+\gamma^{(p-1,q)}$ so $$\partial\bar{\partial}\beta=-\partial\bar{\partial}\beta'+\partial\gamma^{(p-1,q)}=\bar{\partial}\partial\beta'+\partial\gamma^{(p-1,q)}=\\ 
\bar{\partial}\gamma^{(p,q-1)}+\partial\gamma^{(p-1,q)}=(\partial+\bar{\partial})\gamma^{(p,q-1)}+(\partial+\bar{\partial})\gamma^{(p-1,q)}=d\gamma=\alpha$$
Here, we used that $\partial$ and $\bar{\partial}$ anti-commute on $\Delta$, as well as $\partial\gamma^{(p-1,q)}=(\partial+\bar{\partial})\gamma^{(p-1,q)}$ because $\bar{\partial}\gamma^{(p-1,q)}=0$, as was noted in the first paragraph. Similar reasoning applies to the other summand, so we have the desired statement. The converse statement $\alpha=\partial\bar{\partial}\beta\implies d\alpha=0$ is trivial.

Comment: Thank you ! Amazing solution.

Comment: Shouldn't $\partial$ and $\bar \partial$ *anti*commute, regardless  of the manifold we are working on?

Comment: Yes that's true. You actually have to modify the sign, to make it work out. Fixed now. @red_trumpet

Answer (score 2):

This is probably overkill, but it can also be seen as an application of the $\partial \bar \partial$-lemma[1] from Kähler manifolds:

> **Proposition 6.17** Let $X$ be a Kähler manifold, and let $\omega$ be a form which is both $\partial$ and $\bar \partial$-closed. Then if $\omega$ is $d$ or $\partial$ or $\bar \partial$-exact, there exists a form $\chi$ such that $\omega = \partial \bar \partial \chi$.

In your application, $\alpha$ is a $d$-closed form of type $(p,q)$ by assumption. In particular it is also $\partial$ and $\bar \partial$ closed. By the ordinary Poincaré Lemma, $\alpha$ is $d$-exact. So the $\partial \bar \partial$-lemma applies and shows that $\alpha = \partial \bar \partial \chi$ for some $(p+q-2)$-form $\chi$. Take $\beta$ as the $(p-1, q-1)$ component of $\chi$, then still $\partial \bar \partial \beta = \alpha$ (because no other components of $\chi$ survive applying $\partial \bar \partial$).

[1] Voisin, *Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry, I*

Comment: In my opinion, using this lemma is somewhat circular reasoning: one of the reasons why Kähler manifolds are interesting, is because the $\partial\bar{\partial}$-lemma holds automatically, when it does not for a general complex manifold. The Bott-Chern cohomology of a complex manifold is a measure of the failure of this lemma. Seeing that the lemma carries over from polydiscs to Kähler manifolds is an important motivation for defining Bott-Chern cohomology. Anyway, you're still correct - I just think it's somewhat backwards to use this argument.

Comment: In fact I know this lemma, but it seem very strong to me to use it in this example, so I didn't use it. but it's also true. Thank you.